Error Calling AWS Lambda from an Aurora Postgres Trigger
I have an RDS Aurora Postgres cluster from which I would like to invoke a lambda function. I followed all the instructions in the documentation here, but I still get an error every time.
Calling:
SELECT * FROM aws_lambda.invoke('myLambdaARN', '{"body": "Hello from Postgres!"}'::json);

Will produce this error:
ERROR:  invoke API failed
DETAIL:  AWS Lambda client returned 'The security token included in the request is invalid.'.

My cluster is in a private subnet so I double checked that I have an endpoint setup for my lambda service. I also made sure that my security groups setup was ok and that RDS can call my lambda. My IAM role seems to be setup properly too.
I'm really stomped on this one and it's super hard to know what token and why it would be "invalid".
Any help is greatly appreciated!
